# Published Web App (ASP .net) isn't working

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created a simple MVC ASP.net application using .net 6.0 framework on visual studio(VS) 2022 with connectivity to SQL server deployed on Azure.

There is just one database and one table on SQL Server. When I execute the code using IIS express on visual studio, its works just fine.

Next I publish the application on Azure on web-app, publishing is successful but getting this error on browser - "This page isn't working at the moment sqlapp1411.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest, check your error log, there is an unhandled exception out there giving an error 500. Check it to have an idea of what's going on.

Comment: `SQL server deployed on Azure` seems that you sql server is on Azure, then if you add the firewall for your azure web app?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the connection string once.Have you added the Azure SQL Connection string in `Portal` =>`Your  App Service` => `Configuration`  section
- Go to Azure portal => choose your database=> Security = >Firewall and Network Security ,
  Allow Azure services and resources to access this server to  "Yes", save and refresh your App.

[image]

- Enable  `Application Logging (Filesystem)`, `Detailed error messages` and `Failed request tracing` in `App Service logs`
  Path : Azure portal => Your App Service = >App Service Logs

[image]

- Use  KUDU console at [https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net](https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/) to check if there are any errors errors.Refer [`KUDU`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)
- Add [`Application Insights`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/monitor/) to your application and log those errors when you start the application

Please refer [ASP.NET app to Azure with Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184019/internal-server-error-500-after-publishing-a-project-to-azure) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton, below mentioned point resolved the issue.

Go to **Azure portal** => **choose your database**=> **Security = >Firewall and Network Security** , Allow Azure services and resources to access this server to "**Yes**", save and refresh your App.

Connection string still resides in appsettings.json file, I am yet to move it to **Portal** =>**Your  App Service** => **Configuration** section.

Thanks for the suggestions and resolution again.

Thanks,
Hitendra